# Error on seed self-referencing table MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management) to create a self-referencing table. I have this in the seed method:

```
            var menuItems = new List<Subcomponent>{
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 1},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 2},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 3},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 4},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 5},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 1, ParentSubcomponentId = 1},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 2, ParentSubcomponentId = 1},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 3, ParentSubcomponentId = 1},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 1, ParentSubcomponentId = 7},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 2, ParentSubcomponentId = 7},
    new Subcomponent{TipoSub = "Testes", NomeSub = "Testes", NotaMinimaSub = 9, PesoSub = 10, Ordem = 3, ParentSubcomponentId = 7}
};
            menu.SubcomponentsComp = menuItems;
            context.Components.AddOrUpdate(m => m.SubcomponentsComp, menu);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

just like in the tutorial. But it gives this error when i try to update the database:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'SGP.Models.Subcomponent'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

Anyone has an idea why is this error appearing? Thanks

Comment: `context.Components.AddOrUpdate(m => m.SubcomponentsComp, menu);` this statement is the culprit, should be doing something like `context.Components.AddOrUpdate(m => m.ID, menu);` or `context.Components.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Name, menu);` because SubcomponentsComp is a type

Comment: That's right, thanks